# React-Native +Redux Example : invariant violation objects are not valid as a react child (found objects with keys {s1})

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I wanted to use redux to store values from a dropdown menu, and use it later as an example case for my app, but it always throws the Invariant Violation
Here is my App.js

```
          export default class App extends Component{
             render() {
              const store = createStore(reducers, {},applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
              return (
               <Provider store={store}>
                  <Picker />
                </Provider>
              );
            }
          }
```

Picker.js

```
        class Picker extends Component {
          ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
          constructor() {
            super();
            this.onChangeText = this.onChangeText.bind(this);
            this.handleDestroyItem = this.handleDestroyItem.bind(this);
          }
          ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });

          onChangeText(text) {
            this.props.dispatch({ type: 'ADD_ITEM', text });
          }
          handleDestroyItem(id) {
            this.props.dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_ITEM', id });
          }
          renderRow = (rowData, sectionID, rowID) => {
            return (
              <View>
                <Text>{rowData}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {
                    this.handleDestroyItem(rowID);
                  }}>
                  <Text>Delete</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            );
          };
          render() {
            let data = [{ value: 'Banana' }, { value: 'Mango' }];
            return (
              <View>
                <Dropdown label="Add Commodity"  data={data}   onChangeText={this.onChangeText} />
                <ListView dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.dataSource)}   renderRow={this.renderRow}     enableEmptySections />
              </View>
            );
          }
        }
        const dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
          rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
        });

        function mapStateToProps(state) {
          return {
            dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(state),
          };
        }
```

the reducer folder has a index file which has a reducer and a it is linked with datareducer